# Why phonegap can only get one of my contacts?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

My code is:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        function onSuccess(contacts) {
            console.log(contacts.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                console.log("ID: " + i);
                console.log("DisplayName: "  + contacts[i].displayName);
                console.log("phoneNumbers: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
            }
        }

    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    };

    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";
    filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

The result is :
1
ID : 0
DisplayName: xxxxx
phoneNumbers: xxxxxxxx

Why? There is more than one item in my mobilephone.

Comment: Your contacts length is 1 as given by console.log(contacts.length); and so displaying single data

Answer (score 1):

The default for multiple changed from true to false in the W3C
contacts specification. Mention options.multiple=true it will work.

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple=true;
filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];
navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply set `options.multiple=true` and if this doesnt work simply add a fifth parameter as `true` in your `navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);` like this

```
navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options,true);
```

here, true tells if the user is expecting multiple contacts or not. please refer to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/doc/index.md#parameters) official documentation.